# After while exits, it takes a long time to continue

Tags: python, sikuli

Here is my script:

```
while exists(img1,20):
  if exists(img1):
     click(img2)
click(exists(img3,100))
click(exists(img4,100))
```

All is good, but the problem is after executing `click(img2)`, there is about a 15-20 second delay before it continues to the next line, even though img3 is already visible.

I tried adding `sleep` and `wait` after `click(img2)` but this did not solve my problem.

What must I add add after `click(img2)` so I can continue to the next line without waiting?

Comment: What language is this? It doesn't look like anything I've ever seen.

Comment: Im sorry for my bad english:)

Comment: No, I mean the programming language. The closest match I can think of is miscapitalized Python.

Answer (score 3):

In fact, there is *exactly* a 20-second delay after `click(img2)`.  This is because you told it to spend up to 20 seconds looking for `img1`, which no longer exists.

You may want to read the documentation for the functions you're calling ([here is `exists`](http://doc.sikuli.org/region.html#Region.exists), where you can read about the timeout parameter).

You're also doing some very strange things, like checking if `img1` exists twice in a row (once in the `while` and then in the `if`), and you say that you tried adding `sleep` and `wait` statements to make the code wait less. (??)  You may want to get someone to help you out.